# Rendering a nunjucks template from the client side

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I created a custom schema field type, which is just an input that makes a request to an api with that input's value as a query string parameter.
So on the client-side this is basically what I have:

```
self.populate = function(object, name, $field, $el, field, callback) {
    $field.on('textchange', function() {
        fetchData();
    });
}
```

The api returns a list of items that I would like to render using a nunjucks template from the client-side. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered using the frontend to ping a backend route with the api data and having the backend return a rendered template? That would be a two-step approach to solving the issue. I can elaborate on that.

Comment: Yes, that is how our own admin interface renders markup, we always talk to a server side route to get something rendered. We do not load nunjucks in the browser. However Nunjucks does suppor* being used in the browser and if you want to make it part of your own frontend code you can do that, see the Nunjucks documentation for how that is done.